# laravel unique validation rule based on another column value

Tags: validation, laravel-4, unique

I need to do unique validation of the element named `temp_name` based on another column value `temp_mode`. that is the `temp_name` must be unique when `temp_mode` value is `email`. I did the rule as like this

`'temp_name'   => 'unique:templates,temp_name,NULL,temp_id,temp_mode,email'`

where `templates` is the db name. this didn't worked. it always shows `This template name is already present` for all values of `temp_mode`. i know there will be some other way to achieve this. can anyone please give me an idea to solve this issue.

**Edit**

From the below answer i've tried this code

```
$rules = array(
      'temp_txt'  => 'required',

    );

     $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);
     $validator->sometimes('temp_name', 'unique:templates', function($input){
return $input->temp_mode == 'email';
});
```

But this shows me the error

```
BadMethodCallException  Method [sometimes] does not exist
```

should i install any additional feature into my project in order to use `sometimes`??

Answer (score 0):

You can [conditionally add validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) using `sometimes`:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);
$validator->sometimes('temp_name', 'unique:templates', function($input){
    return $input->temp_mode == 'email';
});
if($validator->passes()){
    // yay
}
```

Comment: is it right if i gave the code inside function($input) as like this `return $input->temp_mode = Input::get('temp_mode'); `  ??

Comment: No that would make no sense? What's wrong with my code? Ah you mean the values should be `email`?

Comment: thanks.. one more doubt..should i require any additional library to be included in my project to user `sometimes` ? because when i run this code in my project it shows this error `Method [sometimes] does not exist. `

Comment: Definitely not. Please edit your question and add the code that's not working

Comment: Strange... Please check if you find `public function sometimes(..` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php`